# Send a Unicode character to active window on X

Tags: unicode, input, x11

I am looking for a way to send Unicode characters to the active window. Currently, I have a solution that I'm not happy with. Here it is (in Python):

```
Xlib.display.Display.change_keyboard_mapping(keycode, [{ordchar}])
// send the keycode with KeyPress and KeyRelease
sleep(0.05)
```

In the above code, `keycode` is an arbitrary number between 8 and 255, and `ordchar` is the Unicode code point to be sent.

I have two problems with the above code:

1. The program has to modify the keymap. This circumvents the limitation that only cca. 250 keycodes are available to send.
2. I have to insert a delay between sending two characters, otherwise the keymap change between them might not register. A delay of 0.05 eradicates emissions, but the characters arrive with a visible lag.

Comment: This is the only way to send key events. Better eliminate the need to send events altogether.

Comment: @n.m. I would love to eliminate this need, but I'll elaborate some more, and you'll see why it is not possible. The idea is that an input device sends data through a serial port, which is converted to a string that might contain Unicode characters, and this string should arrive at the active window. It would be possible to make a module for scim or uim, which handle Unicode input well, but 1. the solution should be reasonably portable across Linux, Windows and Mac as well, 2. all of which I described is already implemented in Python, and I am not too keen on porting it.

Comment: FWIW, the `sleep` can be avoided by using the display's `sync` method instead. That's what `xdotool type` does if it cannot figure out how to otherwise emulate the keypress.